# Hide specific value of option form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, categories

I have this code generated with plugin arrays categories. I need hide some specifics categories from form, like "pro", "basico" and "Todas las Provincias.

```
<select id="category_name" class="taxonomies-filter-widget-input tax-with-childrens" name="category_name">
<option value="0">Todas</option>
<option class="level-0" value="pro">pro</option>
<option class="level-0" value="basico">basico</option>
<option class="level-0" value="todas-las-provincias">Todas las Provincias</option>
<option class="level-0" value="alava">Álava</option>
<option class="level-0" value="albacete">Albacete</option>
<option class="level-0" value="alicante">Alicante</option>
<option class="level-0" value="almeria">Almería</option>
<option class="level-0" value="avila">Ávila</option>
<option class="level-0" value="teruel">Teruel</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

```
(function($) {
$("select > option[value='pro']").remove();
$("select > option[value='basico']").remove()
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var toHideValues = ["pro", "basico", "todas-las-provincias"];
    $('#category_name option').each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), toHideValues) !== -1) {
            $option.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/p6fY7/

Comment: Sorry, but your answer don't work, but the other do it. Some wrong in your code? or my error? i don't know...

Comment: The code on jsfiddle works =). So i guess its your implementation. I hide the option, not remove it, maybe that's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

this would do just what you need

```
var el = "alava";
$('select option[value="' + el + '"]').hide();
```

here is a working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/vrcrP/

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
$('.level-0').each(function(){
var value = $(this).attr('value');
if (value == 'pro' || value == 'basico' || value == 'Todas las Provincias' ) {
$(this).hide();
}
});
```